# CORS Firebase Python on_call Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, cors

According to this documentation [Configuring CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events?gen=2nd#configuring_cors_cross-origin_resource_sharing) I tried to implement the CORS for my Firebase CF in Python like the following:

```
@https_fn.on_call(region='europe-west3', cors=options.CorsOptions(
        cors_origins="*",
        cors_methods=["get", "post"],))
def some_function():
 ...
```

Then I deployed succesfully the CF to firebase with `firebase deploy --only functions:some_function`

Even though I entered * for testing purposes since I was also failing with r"https://my-domain-1a0a0.web.app" in the cors_origins I still get

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://europe-west3-my-domain.cloudfunctions.net/some_function'
> from origin 'https://my-domain.web.app' has been
> blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass
> access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is
> present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your
> needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with
> CORS disabled.

Am i missing something??

Comment: This is a popular question on StackOverflow. Which other answers that match your problem have you researched? Put those links in your question with details on why those answers did not help. Those details will help with debugging. Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-cloud-functions+cors)

Comment: We also need details about the function. Is it public or has IAP enabled (authorization)? If IAP is enabled, then you must also enable CORS support in IAP. https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/customizing#allowing_http_options_requests_cors_preflight

Comment: @JohnHanley Python;CF;v2;on_call. If you find a link, let me know.

Comment: @JohnHanley This is a normal v2 Python CF as mentioned in the GitHub examples: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python/blob/main/example/functions/main.py

I didn't add any authentication, but it does run in my own private Firebase space.

Comment: Your client [most likely](https://jub0bs.com/posts/2023-02-08-fearless-cors/#9-ease-troubleshooting-by-eschewing-shortcuts-during-preflight) includes a request header that is not allowed in your CORS configuration. Inspect the `Access-Control-Request-Headers` header in the preflight request.

Comment: @jub0bs I did inspect it and found the following: `Access-Control-Request-Headers:
authorization,content-type`

Comment: @Georgios There you go. You need to allow those two request headers in your CORS configuration.

Comment: @jub0bs How though? The `options.CorsOptions` object only has two properties: `cors_origins` and `cors_methods` and the official documentation doesn't state anything about this. I am scratching my head

Comment: @Georgios I had to look up [the source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python/blob/7f83050dc44f7877a58a590a5aae1006a6f14358/src/firebase_functions/options.py#L54) myself, but you're right! It seems that this library is not advanced enough to let you configure allowed request headers.

Comment: However, because `firebase_functions` [relies on](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python/blob/7f83050dc44f7877a58a590a5aae1006a6f14358/src/firebase_functions/options.py#L57) [flask-cors](https://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/configuration.html) under the hood, and because [the latter supports specifying allowed request headers](https://flask-cors.corydolphin.com/en/latest/configuration.html#configuration-options), adding support for that in `firebase_functions` should be easy. Why don't you open an issue or a PR on https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-python?

Comment: @jub0bs Thank you so much for the support. Well, I guess the next thing I have to do is to open an issue. I thought that this was a standard procedure and should have already been implemented.

Comment: I asked for more details but you did not provide them. Tip: a CORS error is not always a CORS problem. Use the CLI tool `curl` to test the endpoint. You can control the HTTP request headers to review the response.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `options` solved this for me:

```
@https_fn.on_call(region='europe-west3', cors=options.CorsOptions(
        cors_origins="*",
        cors_methods=["get", "post", "options"],))
def some_function():
```